# Why do I have the option of converting a Web Application to a Web Application in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

If I right-click a newly added "MVC4 Web Application" in my solution, I have the option "Convert to Web Application".

What does this do to the project? 
I thought this project already was a Web Application?